# Google end point gives Invalid HTTP template in logs for GET /

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, openapi

I am using google end points to deploy some of my apis. I am exposing health API on [**GET /**] which returns http 200 so that GKE ingress can consider my container as healthy by invoking this API.

But when I am invoking this end point using [ip-address/], end point always complains method not exist.
This works fine for path [ip-address/hello]

**Ask:** Should I configure / end point in some different manner.

Below are the starter logs of ESP (GKE extensible service proxy container)

```
nginx: [warn] Using trusted CA certificates file: /etc/nginx/trusted-ca-certificates.crt
2020/06/02 11:33:13[error]1#1: Invalid HTTP template: /
2020/06/02 11:33:13[error]1#1: Failed to add http rule: selector: "1.abcd_api_endpoints_my_app_cloud_goog.GetHealth"
get: "/"
```

My open api sepecification yaml

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  title: Dummy API
  description: Dummy API
  version: 1.0.0
host: abcd-api.endpoints.my-app.cloud.goog
consumes:
  - application/json
produces:
  - application/json
schemes:
  - http
paths:
  /:
    get:
      description: Logs service health status
      operationId: getHealth
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Logs service health.
  /hello:
    get:
      description: Returns Hello World
      operationId: helloWorld
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Returns Hello World
```

Comment: What happens when you manually try and reach "/" using curl?

Comment: This esp endpoint is behaving as a front gate for my backend service so request fails even with curl. But curl on GET / from inside the container succeeds.

Comment: What is we re-work the story so that instead of `/` for the health check we change to `/health`?

Answer (score 2):

After reading through Google end points limitation for esp, I came to know that requests on root path are rejected by esp.

https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-limitations#operations_on_url_root_path_

To resolve this problem and providing health end point esp provides --healthz paramter.

https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/specify-proxy-startup-options

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-samples/blob/master/k8s/esp_echo_gke_ingress.yaml